Concurrent Locks issue
I'm new to Database and Microservices. I'm trying to understand an edge case which is very unlikely to happen but can happen. Assume there in 1 object in inventory and two users trying to process at same time(exact same time) -meaning two service is trying make a lock simultaneously how is this case handle?
(I understand lock give access to one thread only but think in terms of micro-services, how it's handled ?)

You must ensure with database statements only one service can modify a record at a time.

The whole point is of locks in databases is to avoid issues with concurrent changes. If 2 things try to obtain the same lock, 1 will win.

Yes, I'm trying to understand the concept behind it, how this is achieved? In terms of microservices there is a concept of overbooking via race condition but many application are able to workaround it. So trying to learn how this is handled in those applications.

Rocks from a microservices perspective are usually implemented through databases.
It is possible through RDBMS, Redis, etc., and usually obtains the request time in milliseconds and nanoseconds by name.
Since no matter how many requests are made at the same time, the service requested first obtains a lock based on the request time (ex. LOCK_2024070810551111111) and releases the lock acquired after logic execution.
